# Applying SonarQube alerts on subprojects / components

Tags: sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project on which SonarQube analyzes the reactor for me. I created a quality profile and specified an alert on code coverage.

The problem is that I do not get an alert when any of my subprojects have a code coverage of less than X percent. On the alert page it is stated:

```
"Only project measures are checked against thresholds. Modules, packages and classes are ignored."
```

I suppose that with modules SonarQube means subprojects / components (of my reactor) and I was wondering why SonarQube does not support this.

I think it would be nice to get an alert if any of my subprojects had a code coverage level of less than X percent. Am I missing something?

Thanks and best, 
Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4367